# How can I get a selected value from DateTimePicker using 'react-datetime'

Tags: reactjs

I want to get a selected value from my DateTimePicker. instead of seeing the value I see [Object object]

This is my DateTimePicker.

```
  import React from 'react';

    import momentLocaliser from 'react-widgets-moment';

    import DateTime from 'react-datetime';

   import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import classNames from 'classnames';

  const moment = require('moment');

  moment.locale('es');

  momentLocaliser(moment);


   const handleChange = (e) =>{

      const valueOfInput = moment(e.target.value).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');

    return valueOfInput;

    }

    const DateTimePickerInput = ({
           label,
           format,
           input,
           width,
           placeholder,
           selected,
           tooltip,
           tooltipPlacement,
           disabled,
          defaultValue,
          inputProps,
           meta: { valid, touched, error},
          //input: { onChange, value, onBlur},
          showTime,
          ...props
           }) => {

          const classes = classNames('form-group', {
           'has-error': (touched && !valid),
            'has-success': (touched && !valid)
         })
       return (
          <div className={classes}>
             <label htmlFor={input.name}>{label}</label> <br />
             <DateTime

            name = {input.name}
            locale='es'
            dateFormat= "DD-MM-YYYY"
            timeFormat= "HH:mm"

          onChange = {(changedVal) => handleChange(changedVal)}

          inputProps={{disabled: true, placeholder: {handleChange}}} //In placeholder is the issue

         />

        {(!valid && touched) &&
             <p className='help-block'>{error}</p>
           }
          </div>
         );
      };

     DateTimePickerInput.propTypes = {
         disabled: PropTypes.bool,
         input: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
         label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
         meta: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
         placeholder: PropTypes.string,
         tooltip: PropTypes.string,
         tooltipPlacement: PropTypes.string
      }




    export default DateTimePickerInput;
```

I expect getting the selected value from dateTimePicker but only instead see that I see [Object object].

I need solve now.

I believe if I declare onChange like parameter when I'm declaring DateTimePickerInput and assign to placeholder onChange, things would change. But I'm not sure. I need anyone tells me what is wrong.

Comment: Please follow your question and ask subsequent queries if the answer didn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **onChange**: Callback trigger when the date changes. The callback receives the selected **moment object** as only parameter, if the date in the input is valid. If the date in the input is not valid, the callback receives the value of the input (a string).

So,change `moment(e.target.value)` to `moment(e.toDate())`

```
const handleChange = (e) =>{
   const valueOfInput = moment(e.toDate()).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');

   return valueOfInput;
   }

  inputProps={{ placeholder:moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'), disabled: true }}
```

Comment: I just solved . inputProps= {{ placeholder: !input.value ? 'please enter a date' ? input.value, disabled: true}}

Comment: Hi! I know it's different from the question. But how could I get `e.target.name` in `moment`?